# DefaultSQLExecutionStrategy missing

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have download EF6 using nuget (version 6.0.21010).

I can't find the DefaultSQLExecutionStrategy mentioned in this EF6 article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835

Can anyone tell me where it is... my System.Data.Entity.SqlServer only has SqlAzureExecutionStrategy and four other classes, but no DefaultSQLExecutionStrategy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.cs. Note that this class is internal and is in the EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll.

**EDIT**

The article has been updated and it now says that this type is internal.

Comment: I have a reference to this dll, and yet when I look in the object browser (right click the dll, and choose object browser), it only has the classes SQLAzureExecutionStrategy, SQLFunctions, SQLProviderServices, SQLServerMigrationSqlGenerator and SQLSpatialFunctions...

Comment: Just noticed - it's an internal class. This strategy is set by default. I think the doc should be updated to reflect this.

Comment: @user1503235 - the article has been updated accordingly. Thanks for reporting.